# Docker networking suddenly fails after running "docker system prune" command

Tags: networking, docker

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that I have been using for months.  Yesterday, for some oddball reason, I decided to do `docker system prune`.  Now, when I try to do `docker-compose up -d`, I now get this message several times:

> `user specified IP address is only supported when connecting to networks with user configured subnets`

How do I troubleshoot this problem?  *(It worked fine until I did "prune.")*

Comment: Could you add your docker-compose.yml file? Show also output of the command ``docker network inspect name_of_your_network``.

Comment: Not quite easily today.  The inspect output shows, among other things, `Subnet 172.21.0.0/16' with the expected `Gateway`.  *But* I notice in the `Network:` section of my yaml file, the IP-address is *not* in that range.  Perhaps this is part of the problem.  (All of the networks are `bridge` type.)

Comment: My Docker friends are telling me that I should just ditch the IP-address specs and arrange for the environment-files and such to refer by service-name ... they're probably right.

Comment: Check also logs by ``docker logs container_name`` command. Anyway, content of your "docker-compose.yml" file can be helpful.